# A simple way to clone a complex object

Tags: delphi, clone, assign

I have a class, that looks like this:

```
TCharacter = class (TData)
  Images:    array of T_Variable_Image;
  Description:        String;
  Place:              TPlace;   
  Dialogues:          TSequenceData;    
  Abilities: array of TAbility;       
  Inventory:          TContainer;       
  Journal:            TJournal;        
  SideName:           String;
  Side:               Integer;                 
  Status:             String;                
  Disabled:           Boolean;
```

As you can see, half of its fields are other classes or records, many of which have similarly complex structure. TCharacter inherits from TData, that in turn inherits from TPersistent - I thought, that its Assign method would help me easily clone an instance of TCharacter into another instance. Alas, it wasn't so easy. So my question is - what is the best way for me to clone an instance without losing any data or creating a pointer, that would change along with its original.

Comment: Using `Assign` is indeed the right way to go. But you must override `Assign` in each new class you create.

Comment: FYI, the Delphi RTL already has a [`TCharacter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Character.TCharacter) class, so you should consider renaming your class to something else more unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TPersistent.Assign/To()` method is what you are looking for.  You just need to *implement* it in your various classes, for example (may require some tweaking, depending on your actual class designs):

```pascal
type
  TData = class (TPersistent)
    ...
    function Clone: TData;
  end;

  TDataClass = class of TData;

  T_Variable_Image = class (TData)
    ...
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  end;

  TPlace = class (TData)
    ...
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  end;

  TSequenceData = class (TData)
    ...
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  end;

  TAbility = class (TData)
    ...
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  end;

  TContainer = class (TData)
    ...
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  end;

  TJournal = class (TData)
    ...
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  end;        

  TCharacter = class (TData)
    Images:    array of T_Variable_Image;
    Description:        String;
    Place:              TPlace;   
    Dialogues:          TSequenceData;    
    Abilities: array of TAbility;       
    Inventory:          TContainer;       
    Journal:            TJournal;        
    SideName:           String;
    Side:               Integer;                 
    Status:             String;                
    Disabled:           Boolean;      
    ...
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  end;

...

function TData.Clone: TData;
begin
  Result := TDataClass(ClassType).Create;
  try
    Result.Assign(Self);
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;

...

procedure TCharacter.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
var
  Src: TCharacter;
  I : Integer;
begin
  if Source is TCharacter then
  begin
    Src := TCharacter(Source);

    for I := Low(Images) to High(Images) do
    begin
      Images[I].Free;
    end;
    SetLength(Images, Length(Src.Images));
    for I := Low(Src.Images) to High(Src.Images) do
    begin
      Images[I] := T_Variable_Image(Src.Images[I].Clone);
    end;

    Description := Src.Description;
    Place.Assign(Src.Place);
    Dialogues.Assign(Src.Dialogues);

    for I := Low(Abilities) to High(Abilities) do
    begin
      Abilities[I].Free;
    end;
    SetLength(Abilities, Length(Src.Abilities));
    for I := Low(Src.Abilities) to High(Src.Abilities) do
    begin
      Abilities[I] := TAbility(Src.Abilities[I].Clone);
    end;

    Inventory.Assign(Src.Inventory);
    Journal.Assign(Src.Journal);
    SideName := Src.SideName;
    Side := Src.Side;
    Status := Src.Status;
    Disabled = Src.Disabled;
  end else
    inherited;
end;

// implement Assign() for your other classes as needed...
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the Assign method in your class, assigning the new fields/properties you introduce. Don't forget to call inherited.
If fields are classes, you should call their Assign method and if you created those classes, don't forget to override their Assign method.

Comment: Of course, `Assign` isn't present in every class derived from `TObject`, but only in descendants of `TPersistent`.

Comment: "*Don't forget to call inherited*" - unless the next ancestor to implement `Assign()` is `TPersistent` itself and your class does not implement `AssignTo()`. `TPersistent.Assign()` calls `AssignTo()`, and if `AssignTo()` is not overridden then `TPersistent.AssignTo()` will raise an `EConvertError` exception.